# architectural issue somewhat related to form submit

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I've got a webapp. In the backend I've got c#. In the front I have some typescript, html and knockoutjs.

My question is about how to code the result of a request.  I have a form, with only 3 form fields ... and a submit button. Once the user clicks the submit button a request is being send (using ajax ) to a wcf service on the server. The server responds in json.  The result set contains a resultcode (an enum of various possible result situations). Each resultcode value requires a specific result message to be presented to the user. Also, some resultcode values require different 'next-action' buttons to be presented to the user.

My question is:
- where should the response TEXT be coming from? Should the server include the response TEXT in the resultset too? Or should the client use the resultcode value to find the corresponding resultmessage?
- what would be the best way to make this multilingual?  Should multilingual be solved clientside/serverside?

Any feedback is appreciated!
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, the only text that you determine client side should be static text, such as labels and maybe validation messages. These are the the strings that would reside in localization/resource files.

Any data that is dynamic should be retrieved from the server. The API should have some way to determine the appropriate language and return the appropriate data to you.

Answer (score 1):

> Should multilingual be solved clientside/serverside

For SPAs we tend to request a js file, which is a simple json key value (message) blob. Which version (language) of the file is returned is determined by user settings on the server.

Comment: basarat, thanx (again). Could you point me to a (live) example website which is made as a multilingual asp site, preferably using knockoutjs?